# Spring security (HttpSecurity) with keycloak setup

Tags: java, spring, security, keycloak

I have the following setup:

1. An angular based frontend, which communicates with a
2. java based backend, which in turn communicates
3. with 3rd party services in the organization.

Frontend/backend access is secured with oauth2 which queries a keycloak server. This keycloak server authenticates users for both my application and the 3rd party services my backend is accessing.
The code to obtain the access token for the 3rd party services is as follows (in fact this is the code where the problem occurs: when calling `template.getAccessToken()`, see also further below):

```
  private void setAccessToken(HttpRequest request) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceOwnerDetails());
    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = template.getAccessToken();
    headers.setAuthorization("Bearer " + accessToken);
    request.setHeaders(headers);
  }
```

The security config is the following:

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
      http.requiresChannel()
          .anyRequest()
          .requiresSecure()
          .and()
          .cors()
          .and()
          .csrf()
          .disable()
          .sessionManagement()
          .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
          .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
          .and()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/accessdenied", "/accessdenied/**", "/style/*")
          .permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/")
          .hasAnyRole(allowedRoles)
          .anyRequest()
          .hasAnyRole(allowedRoles)
          .and()
          .exceptionHandling()
          .accessDeniedPage("/accessdenied");
```

When requiring authentication for both frontend/GUI access and 3rd party services queried by the backend, this works fine.

My problem is as follows:
Under certain conditions (tester) I want a user to not have to be authenticated for frontend/GUI access. However, in order to access the 3rd party services, authentication is always required.

To access the frontend without authentication I can do a simple configuration such as:

```
 http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
```

With this, I can access the GUI without being authenticated (which is what I want) but when it comes to obtaining the oauth2 access token via `template.getAccessToken()` (see above) an exception is thrown

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)
```

So, I think what I am looking for is the proper security configuration.
How can I configure spring security such that it does not authenticate GUI/frontend access but still gets the access token for the 3rd party services? Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in your config class

```
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.jwk.JwkTokenStore;

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer

    public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JwkTokenStore("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs");
        }
    }
```

```
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.jwk.JwkTokenStore;

    @KeycloakConfiguration
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @ComponentScan(
        basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class
    )
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
    public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JwkTokenStore("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.